# tcl/tk: what tk widget can create GUI with "tab"

Tags: user-interface, tabs, widget, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm building a GUI with tcl/tk. I want to build a window with several tabs. what tk widget can i use to make such GUI. I did not find tab widget in manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want ttk::notebook.
  See: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm

Comment: yes. it is tab interface. but what is ttk? i tried to run some sample code but failed. currently i am using tcl/tk 8.5.

Comment: ttk::notebook is available in 8.5: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm . Check and make sure your tclsh and wish are really 8.5 by running `info patchlevel`. Chances are you've got both 8.5 and 8.4 installed and your OS defaults to 8.4. If on linux you may need to do `update-alternatives` to change the default to 8.5. Or simply uninstall 8.4 since 8.5 is backwards compatible with 8.4.

Comment: 8.5 is _mostly_ backwards compatible with 8.4, but not 100%. Alas.